# Validation error placement in Bassistance

Tags: jquery, validation

i'm using Bassasistance jQuery validation and so far it seems to be great! I've a quick question regarding the error placement.

At the moment, as can be seen below, I am targetting the `<small>` tag, which I also use as a hint for what the user should type into the field. If validation fails, I would like to replace the current hardcoded contents with the relevant message from the script. When validation fails it looks like it's just adding another `<small>` element under my own one

Any ideas would be great!

The page can be found online at http://www.st-patricks-day-2011.com/addlisting.asp

Here's the code that I am using

```js
$("#paradeEventForm").validate({
  errorElement: "small",

  rules: {
    name: "required",
    description: "required",
    keywords: "required",
    address: "required",
    country: "required",
    eventDate: "required",
    websiteAddress: "required"
  },

  messages: {
    name: "Please enter a title for your Parade or Event",
    description: "Please enter a description for your Parade or Event",
    keywords: "Please enter some keywords that describe your Parade or Event",
    address: "Please enter the starting point of your Parade or Event",
    country: "Please enter the country where your Parade or Event is taking place",
    eventDate: "Please enter a date for your Parade or Event",
    websiteAddress: "Please enter the website address of you Parade or Event"
  }
});
```

Comment: you may pre-fill the form fields with default data in your server side script which will be considered as the default data. Also you may create an add event to change the default value on click

Comment: @decbrad your link has since died,  I suggest editing the question to update the link or manually include relevant information

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question, you can try replace the small content in the errorPlacement:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    element.searchforyoutsmall.html(error;
},
```

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks! Yeah, that's exactly right! If the small element contains a hint and a validation message is neccessary, then the existing message should be overwritten by the error message. I tried to include the code that you suggested but not having much luck! Complete novice! Can you explain a little or suggest a tutorial online? Thanks a million! DB